# How to use gexiv2 in python?

Tags: python, pygobject, gobject, exiv2, pyexiv2

I just compiled exiv2 and gexiv2 for my debian machiene and now I want to start working with gexiv2 to edit IPTC data using python. The gexiv2 website presents the following line of code:

```
from gi.repository import GExiv2
```

But that already results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

I can't even import gi so I think I'm missing another package!? What do I have to do to make this work as expected?

**UPDATE:** I upgraded my OS to the newest debian version. I can import gi now, but I'm still having trouble with GExiv2.

The following error occurs when importing GExiv2:

```
>>>from gi.repository import GExiv2
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for GExiv2
```

Comment: For me it worked to manually install the [`gir1.2-gexiv2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/gir1.2-gexiv2-0.4/download) package from Ubuntu (I'm using Debian sid).

Answer (score 4):

Hi i had the same problem i fixed it by installing `gir1.2-gexiv2-0.4`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the package you need is [`python3-gi`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python3-gi) or, if you're using Python 2, [`python-gi`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-gi).

Comment: that doesn't exist in my repo. according to the debian website it contains pygi wich is depricated and should be part of gobject now, but i already installed gobject.

Comment: Both packages exist for current stable (wheezy).  I'll add links.

Comment: I upgraded to the newest debian version, but now I'm getting this Error: ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for GExiv2

Comment: Does `$(pkg-config --variable=typelibdir gobject-introspection-1.0)/GExiv2.typelib` exist?  Looking at the libgexiv2 packages on packages.debian.org, it seems like their Debian packages are broken and include neither the GIR nor typelib, which means you should file a bug and, if you want to get it working ASAP, install libgexiv2 from source, circumventing debian's package management system.

Comment: If I type the line you gave me in a console I get: "/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/GExiv2.typelib: No such file or directory". I tried compiling it myself, but having two versions leads to other problems. How can I swap the debian version with my own? I can't just aptitude uninstall it, becaus then it wants to remove gnome, too. I'd also love to file it, but I really don't know how. The reportbug tool of debian is really shitty, because it asks a lot of stuff a novice like me doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I solved it by installing gir1.2-gexiv2-0.4 AND python-gobject